# What should trigger a fetch in react? The user action, state change or absence of valid data?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In this thread I'd like to use react hooks to demostrate each thought.

The problem is when use react to build an app, if an async fetch is required, what should be the trigger of the fetch call?

As an example, we have a `MemberList` component which includes a `<input>` to type filter keyword, a `<button>` to filter list results by keyword, and a `<ul>` to display every member detail:

```
<div>
    <header>
        <input value={keyword} onChange={syncKeywordToState} />
        <button onClick={handleFilter}>Filter Members</button>
    </header>
    {
        isLoading
            ? (
                <ul>
                    {data.map(m => <li key={m.id}>{m.name}</li>)}
                </ul>
            )
            : <Loading />
    }
</div>
```

A `listMember(keyword: string) => Promise<Member[]>` function is also provided to load members by keyword, when fetch is pending, we should display a loading animation instead of a list.

As a result the problem changes to "when we should call `listMember` function and trigger the loading animation".

### User action

The most straightforward thought is to trigger a fetch when the button is clicked, it could be:

```
const MemberList = () => {
    const [members, setMembers] = useState([]);
    const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const handleFilter = useCallback(
        async () => {
            const data = await listMember(keyword);
            setMembers(data);
            setLoading(false);
        },
        [listMember, keyword]
    );

    return (
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
    );
};
```

This works perfectly when use clicks the button, however on the mount of component it will not fetch the initial member list, we need a effect corresponding to older `componentDidMount` lifecycle, since react does not provide a builtin `useDidMount` hook, we have to do it trickly:

```js
useEffect(
    async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        const data = await listMember(keyword);
        setMembers(data);
        setLoading(false);
    },
    [true] // The didMount trick
);
```

I don't think this is a pattern react encourages, the `useEffect` hook is strongly telling us not to distinguish between `didMount` and `didUpdate`, so a standalone `didMount` effect should be avoided with effort.

### State change

The second possible solution is to trigger a fetch when it's depdent state changes:

```
const MemberList = () => {
    const [members, setMembers] = useState([]);
    const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');
    const [filterKeyword, setFilterKeyword] = usetState('');
    const handleFilter = () => setFilterKeyword(keyword); // Apply keyword to filter
    useEffect(
        async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            const data = await listMember(filterKeyword);
            setMembers(data);
            setLaoding(false);
        },
        [listMember, filterKeyword]
    );

    return (
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is deadly simple:

1. When user clicks the button, current input value `keyword` is provided as the `filterKeyword` state.
2. Since the argument of `listMember` changes, it should be invoked with the new value.
3. A fetch is thus triggered as an effect.

I find this solution conceptualy clear, however some issues still raise:

1. It causes a sync state update in effect which we struggle to prevent in earlier versions of react ([no-did-update-set-state](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-did-update-set-state.md))
2. If the argument of fetch is more complex like arrays or objects, reference equal may fail, `useMemo` doesn't help a lot here, this could result in unexpected duplication of fetch calls.

### Absence of valid data

The last concept is "we just fetch a data when we don't have it", state change is a trigger of "change to arguments of fetch" but not a "absence of fetch result", in a cache involved system we can have situations that even a filter is changed, the result list still lives:

```js
const cacheReducer = (caches, {key, value}) => {
    return {
        ...caches,
        [key]: {
            time: Date.now(),
            value,
        },
    };
};

// Cache valid for 5 seconds
const isDataValid = ({time, value}) => !value || (time - Date.now() > 5000);

const MemberList = () => {
    const [members, setMembers] = useState([]);
    const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');
    const [filterKeyword, setFilterKeyword] = usetState('');
    const [caches, addCache] = useReducer({});
    const data = caches[filterKeyword];
    const handleFilter = () => setFilterKeyword(keyword); // Apply keyword to filter
    useEffect(
        async () => {
            if (!isDataValid(data)) {
                setLoading(true);
                const data = await listMember(filterKeyword);
                addCache({key: filterKeyword, value: data});
                setLaoding(false);
            }
        },
        [listMember, filterKeyword, data]
    );

    return (
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
    );
}
```

In this case, when user clicks the button, `filterKeyword` is changes but we also validates the cached data, only fetch it when it is invalid (either not found or expired).

This is a more fined model to manage the relationship of arguments, fetch and its trigger.

---

These 3 solutions is not simply different from each other with their implement, they're more **conceptual models**, I'm wondering which to choose as a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

After your comment, I've understood something more. Anyway I don't agree that you can't replicate the `componentDidMount` behavior because [even the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) say that

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument

---

### MY ORIGINAL ANSWER BELOW

First of all, starting with your first Hooks snippet (the following)

```
const MemberList = () => {
    const [members, setMembers] = useState([]);
    const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const handleFilter = useCallback(
        async () => {
            const data = await listMember(keyword);
            setMembers(data);
            setLoading(false);
        },
        [listMember, keyword]
    );

    return (
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
    );
};
```

you wrote

> however on the component's mount it will not fetch the initial member list, we need an effect corresponding to older componentDidMount

That's not 100% correct... it's correct if you use `useCallback` but if you use `useEffect` you get the same behavior of `componentDidMount`.

Take a look at [my codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pkkn0wy40?expanddevtools=1), the code is the following:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";

const MemberList = () => {
  const [members, setMembers] = useState([]);
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const handleFilter = useEffect(
    async () => {
      console.log("useCallback");
    },
    [/*listMember, */ keyword]
  );

  return <div>...</div>;
};

export default MemberList;
```

I changed it a bit because:

- I don't have the `listMember` function so I replaced it with a `console.log`
- `useCallback` isn't useful for the goal you want to accomplish, you want the `listMember` function to be called when the filter changes but `useCallback` just returns a memoized function... it doesn't invoke it! (see the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback))
- `useEffect`, instead, accomplishes your goal, it invokes the passed function every time the `keyword` filter changes. And it's always called after the first mount (if you take a look at the console you find my log)
- I commented out the `listMember` param you passed because when you're trying to avoid that the side effect id triggered... you must use values, not references! Even if the function does always the same, it can change (especially on React) at every render... and so the side effect is re-triggered because the strict === equality tells that it's changed (in case of functions even the == returns that but I wanted to explain you the difference)... so, for example, don't use arrays but map its values, don't use objects but use their ids... you can use them. obviously, but you need to know what you're doing. Passing `keyword` is enough.

For the rest of your question, it's not so clear to me what you're asking because you reported some different examples... with different behaviors... and you're asking which is the best...?

Comment: In the first snippet `useCallback` only returns a handler so I pass it to `<button onClick>` so that a click on button (user action) could trigger the fetch, this results the "didMount does not fetch" issue.

Comment: If `useEffect` is used, then it becomes my second snippet in which a fetch is triggered by the change of `keyword` state and comes with some other issues I listed in question